# React Router 6 show error in element when using loader

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to show an error message on the same page if there's an error when loading a resource. However, when using loader and errorElement, the user is taken to another page. How can I do it so I show the error on my component and not redirect the user to a new component/view?

Example of what I'm doing:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    children: [
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactId",
        element: <Contact />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

I've tried several things.

When I do the things as in the example, the user is redirected to the errorComponent. That would be fine if the application had a fatal error but not if the application has a 422 error for example. In that case, I would like an error alert/snack to appear.

I've also tried to use the same component for the error. This didn't load the error message that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an `errorElement` for specific routes if you like. The `errorElement` is a sort of "error boundary" for route loading, the closest one at or above a route that is being loaded is rendered when there's an error.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    children: [
      {
        path: "contacts/:contactId",
        element: <Contact />,
        errorElement: <ContactErrorPage />, // <-- specific to route
        loader: contactLoader,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Maybe I did it incorrectly. I created a Notification component and it as the errorElement on the child route. My intention was to show that Notification component within the child component, Contact in the example above. However, what the router does is to show just the error component, in your example above ContactErrorPage. How can I make it so I show the component with the errors and not go to a new component?

Comment: @confused I see. The `errorElement` is what is rendered when an error is thrown during the loading of the route. If you want the routed component to render regardless then I suspect you'll want to add a bit more logic to the loader function to catch any thrown errors and convert the ones you want the component to handle into part of a "normal" response object (*perhaps under an `error` key*) and rethrow all other errors. This would allow the routed component to then render normally and handle the "ok-ish" errors. Does this make sense? Would you like me to add an example?

Comment: Thanks. An example would be great. I think I tried what you say with no luck. My conclusion was that I would need to do the call from the component and handle everything directly there which to me sounds like the opposite of what they were trying to do when adding that functionality.

Comment: @confused Well, yeah, there's always been that option as well, if you didn't want to muck about with loaders and routing error boundaries. I'll clean up the sandbox I've been tinkering with when trying to understand what is or isn't working with regards to the code above and what you are saying to wanted and add it above.

Comment: @confused Sorry for delay: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-show-error-in-element-when-using-loader-uvmwbo?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same component for both `element` and `errorElement` and [`useRouteError`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.1/hooks/use-route-error) in that component

Example : https://replit.com/@ptrkcsk/React-Router-useRouteError

```
import { createBrowserRouter, useRouteError } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <Root />,
    loader: () => {
      throw new Error("Error");
    },
  },
]);

function Root() {
  const routeError = useRouteError();

  return routeError ? routeError.message : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was using a loader that did not end in a "return" statement.

I can't see your rootLoader function, but maybe check that.

The loader must "return" something, such as the Data being loaded. I did not find this documented very well (at least for morons like me) in the react router loader page.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find it on React Router docs, but I guess you can catch the error in the loader. For example:

```
export async function rootLoader() {
  try {
    const contacts = await getContacts();
    return { contacts };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error.message };
  }
}
```

And then, in the Root component do something like this:

```
const Root = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  
  return (
    <>
      (data.contacts && data.contacts.map((contact) => <p>{contact.name}</p>))

      (data.error && <p>{data.error}</p>)
    </>
  );
};

export default Root;
```